# Laravel Trying to Get property of non object (from eloquent model)

Tags: php, laravel, object

Already read some of questions about this problem on stackoverflow and none of that answers apply to me.
When I run:

```
$item_price = ItemPrice::where('item_name',$itemname)->first();
```

and then

```
$item_price->price
```

I get **Trying to get property of non-object** but when I run:

```
dd($item_price = ItemPrice::where('item_name',$itemname)->first());
```

It's returning object with attributes  name, price etc. I don't really understand what is happening here.

Full code:

```
foreach ($inventorydecoded->assets as $asset) {

    $i = 0;
    $a = 0;
    while ($a < 1) {

      if ($inventorydecoded->descriptions[$i]->classid == $asset->classid) {
        $a = 1;
        $classid = $inventorydecoded->descriptions[$i]->classid;
        $itemname = $inventorydecoded->descriptions[$i]->market_hash_name;
        $tradable = $inventorydecoded->descriptions[$i]->tradable;
        $name_color = $inventorydecoded->descriptions[$i]->name_color;

  ;

      }
      $i++;
    } // end of while
      if ($tradable === 1 && strpos_arr($itemname, $blacklist) == false ) {
            $item_price = ItemPrice::whereItemName($itemname)->first();
      //     dd(ItemPrice::where('item_name',$itemname)->first());
            $items[] = ['assetid' => $asset->assetid,'classid'=> $classid,'itemname'=>$itemname,'name_color'=>$name_color,'price'=> $item_price->price];
            $serialized_inventory = serialize($items);

      }
  } // end of foreach
```

Comment: Do you use this code inside `for` or `foreach` loop? Is so, please show full code.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin yeah i did , edited post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using this query in loop, so one of those is empty and returns `null`. So you need to do simple check:

```
if (is_null($item_price)) {
    // There is no price for this item, do something.
}
```

Comment: yeah but problem is there is price for every item

Comment: Add `if (is_null($item_price)) dd('There is no price for this item: '.$itemname);`. It will show you what item it can't find.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$item_price = ItemPrice::whereItemName($itemname)->first();
```